# Ways to import .wrl file to WebGL

Tags: webgl, wrl

i am new with WebGL, i want to ask, is there any way to use .wrl file in WebGL without converting in some another  types (like .json, .obj etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebGL API accepts ArrayBuffers only. Even if your model is .json or .obj, WebGL cant read them, data are being passed in ArrayBuffers. Engine (js engines like three.js, playcanvas, babylon.js) needs to parse model files first.

So WebGL itself can't read .wrl files or any other, but javascript can read binary files => some better engines can accept files with various extensions and work with them, like Three.js with github = https://github.com/lorennorman/octocat-3d/blob/master/stl/octocat_base.stl

I dont know any javascript .wrl reader/parser, but it should be possible to write one.

**EDIT**

Three.js might accept .wrl files, but I was unable to do so. Read more here:   https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3728